# Append row with counts in PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas, sum, append, conditional-statements

I have a data frame with categorical data structured in the following way:

```
index    A    B    C    D
ind1     0    0    1    2
ind2     1    0    2    0
ind3     2    1    0    0
```

I would like to append a row which sums only the instances of `"1"`. The desired result would look like:

```
index    A    B    C    D
ind1     0    0    1    2
ind2     1    0    2    0
ind3     2    1    0    0
count1   1    1    1    0
```

I have imported the table such that all characters are strings and have tried the following:

```
dataframe = dataframe.append(dataframe.applymap(lambda x: str.count(x, "1"))
```

However this results in numerous additional rows without meaning. Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: also are you assuming that the entries are strings or integers? mainly asking because of your use of the `str.count`

Comment: I used dtype=object when creating this data frame to ensure that all characters as represented as strings.

Comment: hm.... then maybe both solutions below won't work as presented, do a `.astype(int)` to get them to work or in the equality checks use `'1'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sum boolean mask `df == 1`:

```
print (df == 1)
           A      B      C      D
index                            
ind1   False  False   True  False
ind2    True  False  False  False
ind3   False   True  False  False


df.loc['count1'] = (df == 1).sum()

print (df)
        A  B  C  D
index             
ind1    0  0  1  2
ind2    1  0  2  0
ind3    2  1  0  0
count1  1  1  1  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want to sum over the `1s` or if you want to count the 1s. This assumes that the `dtype` is not `object`. If it is only @jezrael's solution will work if you check against `'1'` rather than `1`.

To sum over the 1s:

```
sr = df.where(df == 1, 0).sum()
sr.name = 'count1'
df.append(sr)
```

to count over the 1s you can use the approach highlighted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39559101/1764089) by @jezrael

In that case the result is the same since you are summing 1s, but if you wanted to do it over 2 then they will give different results.

Comment: Thanks!! This is very helpful